# Key Sig Note Change

Tags: key-signatures

Key signature has an F sharp and there’s an F (played as F#) to an E# (Played as F)
Some people say to play it as an F because it’s an accidental some say to play it an F#
Which is correct[image]

Comment: That note is an E♯, so you play it as an E♯. In equal temperament E♯and F are the same pitch, but they are not always played this way. Especially note that string players may not play them the same way. But you don't need to play an F♯ here just because of the key signature; the note is not an F (even though you might play an F natural here in equal temperament).

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the same question, but with B# as the note in question instead of E#.

Comment: A good guide to solve this sort of problem is to play the part both ways. Here by itself, either works, but I guess there'll be others playing, and the harmony at that point will only sound good with the correct note - E#.

Comment: Also, in this specific case the E♯ the is the leading-note of F♯ minor.